# linking plugin to nextgen upload call

Tags: wordpress

i want to link my plugin to nextgen upload. 
when users upload images in nextgen gallery,during upload, i want it to go through our plugin as well. we tried different hooks but none is working. any idea will be great.

i tried this

```
  function my_enqueue( $hook ) {
   if ( $hook == 'admin.php' || $hook=='wp_ajax_request-nextgen') {
   //some codes here
 }
  }
```

then

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_request-nextgen', array( &$this, 'other_media_library_nextgen_ajax_callback' ), 9, 2 );
```

but its not firing when we upload images to nextgen gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST[ 'photocrati_ajax' ] ) || $_REQUEST['action'] !== 'upload_image' ) {
        # not an upload image request so
        return;
    }
    # process upload request here
}, 9 );
```

Since, the NextGen action M_Ajax::serve_ajax_request() calls exit() you cannot run after the NextGen action. If you need your action to run after the NextGen action then you can run the NextGen action in your action first, then your action and exit.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST[ 'photocrati_ajax' ] ) || $_REQUEST['action'] !== 'upload_image' ) {
        # not an upload image request so
        return;
    }
    # First do the NextGen action M_Ajax::serve_ajax_request() processing
    $controller = C_Ajax_Controller::get_instance();
    $controller->index_action();
    # Now do your image upload processing here
    # Finally, must exit otherwise NextGen action will be done twice
    exit;
}, 9 );
```

The $_REQUEST looks like this

```
[photocrati_ajax] => 1
[action] => upload_image
[gallery_id] => 0
[gallery_name] => gallery
[nextgen_upload_image_sec] => 496cc9951b
[name] => image.jpg
```